# Element does not appear if order changed

Tags: javascript, html

I displayed 3 `li` elements with HTML and 3 using JavaScript code. If I change my JavaScript `div` tag to last it displays both the `ul` elements, else it's not displaying the HTML `ul` tags. Can you tell me why?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>my javascript eg </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
      function process()
      {
        var sval="<ul> <li> orange</li> <li>blue</li> <li>green</li> </ul> ";
        var divid=document.getElementById("mydiv");
        divid.innerHTML=sval;
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="process()">
    Hi Dude !!!
    <div id="mydiv"/>
      <ul id="u2" onclick="fn1()">
        <li>orange</li>
        <li>blue</li>
        <li>yellow</li>
      </ul>

    <!-- If I place the same div element at last line it doesn't work. -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because `id` is unique, you don't want elements with the same `id`.

Answer (score 1):

use class instead of id, class is used for multiple elements

JS

```
function process()
 {
var sval="<ul> <li> orange</li> <li>blue</li> <li>green</li> </ul> ";
var divclass=document.getElementsByClassName("mydiv");    
for (var i = 0;i<divclass.length;i++){      
    var item = divclass[i];        
    item.innerHTML=sval;
}    
}
```

HTML

```
<body onload="process()">
Hi Dude !!!
    <div class="mydiv"></div>
<ul id="u2" onclick="fn1()">
<li>orange</li>
<li>blue</li>
<li>yellow</li>
</ul>
<div class="mydiv"></div>
</body>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5avtsqnz/6/

Answer (score 0):

It is because you cannot have more than one element in the DOM with the same id. If you do so you will always get only the first element with the id.

See the code, its `getElementById` and not `getElementsById`. So it it always return a single element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this<------------HTML Code--------->SEE THIS YOUR CODE:  http://jsfiddle.net/fbwyyrcL/

```
<body onload="process()">
Hi Dude !!!
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<ul id="u2" onclick="fn1()">
<li>orange</li>
<li>blue</li>
<li>yellow</li>
</ul>
</body>
```

<------------Script code is------->

```
function process()
{
  var sval="<ul> <li> orange</li> <li>blue</li> <li>green</li> </ul> ";
  var divid=document.getElementById("mydiv");
  divid.innerHTML=sval;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have just to close your div tag properly, or to create another div around your primary ul definition.  If you leave the inital ul inside the "mydiv" div, it is overwritten (deleted) after your function run.

Following code has worked for me in IE9:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>my javascript eg</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        function prozess(){
           var sval="<ul> <li> orange</li> <li>blue</li> <li>green</li> </ul>";
           var divid=document.getElementById("mydiv");
           divid.innerHTML=sval;
        };
    </script>
</head>

<body onload = "prozess()">
    Hi Dude !!!
    <div id="mydiv"> </div>

    <ul id="u2" onclick="fn1()">
        <li>orange</li><li>blue</li><li>yellow</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```